# Error when trying to get an int from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and programming in general. I was able to create the required program in Console but want to get one working with Forms as well. I am running into an issue when trying to get int from textboxes.

On Debug I am getting error:

> Error  3   'int' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Dropbox\Classwork\C_Sharp\InProgress\PaintDeterminator\Paint Determinator Form\Paint Determinator Form\Form1.cs  30  57  Paint Determinator Form

Here is the code I've written so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Paint_Determinator_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int LengthtextBox;
            int WidthtextBox;
            int HeighttextBox;
            int paint;
            int answer;

                LengthtextBox = int.Parse(LengthtextBox.Text);
                WidthtextBox = int.Parse(WidthtextBox.Text);
                HeighttextBox = int.Parse(HeighttextBox.Text);
                paint = 350;

                answer = (LengthtextBox * WidthtextBox * HeighttextBox) / paint;

                MessageBox.Show( answer.ToString() );

        }

    }
}

namespace Paint_Determinator_Form
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.WidthtextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.HeighttextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.LengthtextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 29);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(454, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Welcome to Paint Determinator! Please enter the measurements in the appropriate f" +
    "ields below!";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 91);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "Width";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 139);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label3.Text = "Height";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 183);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 13);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label4.Text = "Length";
            // 
            // WidthtextBox
            // 
            this.WidthtextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 83);
            this.WidthtextBox.Name = "WidthtextBox";
            this.WidthtextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.WidthtextBox.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // HeighttextBox
            // 
            this.HeighttextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 131);
            this.HeighttextBox.Name = "HeighttextBox";
            this.HeighttextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.HeighttextBox.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // LengthtextBox
            // 
            this.LengthtextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 183);
            this.LengthtextBox.Name = "LengthtextBox";
            this.LengthtextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.LengthtextBox.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(349, 402);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 9;
            this.button1.Text = "Paint";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(511, 447);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.LengthtextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.HeighttextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.WidthtextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox WidthtextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox HeighttextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox LengthtextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
```

Comment: I highly recommend not defining local variables with the same name as class-level members.  Scoping issues aside, it makes code *very* difficult to understand.

Comment: just a suggestion - don't name your internal variables the same as the textbox controls, it's very confusing.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you all. John I did not know and will amend that in the future. And thank you all for enlightening me and going forward I will not name things the same. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you name your ints like your textboxes? It is really a bad practice and confusing at the uttermost level. As you can see, the compiler thinks that you are using the int variables instead of the textboxes and complains that an int type have no property called Text.

So simply change the name of the ints inside the click method

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        int l;
        int w;
        int h;
        int paint;
        int answer;

        l = int.Parse(LengthtextBox.Text);
        w = int.Parse(WidthtextBox.Text);
        h = int.Parse(HeighttextBox.Text);
        paint = 350;

        answer = (l * w * h) / paint;

         MessageBox.Show( answer.ToString() );
    }
```

Said that, I suggest to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the data typed by your user in a valid integer. The Parse method will throw an exception if your user types something that cannot be translated to an integer, instead `TryParse` returns false without a costly exception

For example

```
  int l;
  if(!Int32.TryParse(LengthtextBox.Text, out l))
  {
       MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid number for Length");
       return;
  }
```

> When the Int32.TryParse returns, the out parameter (l) contains the
>   32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in your
>   textbox, if the conversion succeeds, or zero if the conversion fails

Comment: Steve, Thank you! Still shy of 15 reputation so I can't upvote you, but you explained it in a way that was easy for me to understand. This is for an online course and while the book and online materials are helpful, its hard to get the extrapolation on an issue when you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring locally scoped variables that will replace your actual textboxes.  Yo ushould use local variables that have different names like:

```
int length = int.Parse(LengthtextBox.Text);
int width = int.Parse(WidthtextBox.Text);;
int height = int.Parse(HeighttextBox.Text);;
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated your code, you were using variables with the same names as your actual text boxes... That's not a good idea:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Paint_Determinator_Form
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int length;
                int width;
                int height;
                int paint;
                int answer;

                    length = int.Parse(LengthtextBox.Text);
                    width = int.Parse(WidthtextBox.Text);
                    height = int.Parse(HeighttextBox.Text);
                    paint = 350;

                    answer = (length* width* height) / paint;

                    MessageBox.Show( answer.ToString() );

            }

        }
    }

    namespace Paint_Determinator_Form
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.WidthtextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.HeighttextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.LengthtextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // label1
                // 
                this.label1.AutoSize = true;
                this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 29);
                this.label1.Name = "label1";
                this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(454, 13);
                this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.label1.Text = "Welcome to Paint Determinator! Please enter the measurements in the appropriate f" +
        "ields below!";
                // 
                // label2
                // 
                this.label2.AutoSize = true;
                this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 91);
                this.label2.Name = "label2";
                this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
                this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
                this.label2.Text = "Width";
                // 
                // label3
                // 
                this.label3.AutoSize = true;
                this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 139);
                this.label3.Name = "label3";
                this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
                this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
                this.label3.Text = "Height";
                // 
                // label4
                // 
                this.label4.AutoSize = true;
                this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 183);
                this.label4.Name = "label4";
                this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 13);
                this.label4.TabIndex = 3;
                this.label4.Text = "Length";
                // 
                // WidthtextBox
                // 
                this.WidthtextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 83);
                this.WidthtextBox.Name = "WidthtextBox";
                this.WidthtextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
                this.WidthtextBox.TabIndex = 5;
                // 
                // HeighttextBox
                // 
                this.HeighttextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 131);
                this.HeighttextBox.Name = "HeighttextBox";
                this.HeighttextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
                this.HeighttextBox.TabIndex = 6;
                // 
                // LengthtextBox
                // 
                this.LengthtextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 183);
                this.LengthtextBox.Name = "LengthtextBox";
                this.LengthtextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
                this.LengthtextBox.TabIndex = 7;
                // 
                // button1
                // 
                this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(349, 402);
                this.button1.Name = "button1";
                this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                this.button1.TabIndex = 9;
                this.button1.Text = "Paint";
                this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(511, 447);
                this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.LengthtextBox);
                this.Controls.Add(this.HeighttextBox);
                this.Controls.Add(this.WidthtextBox);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "Form1";
                this.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.PerformLayout();

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox WidthtextBox;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox HeighttextBox;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox LengthtextBox;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        }
```

Comment: Your new variable names are kind of misleading.  I would intuitively expect things like `textBoxLength` and `textBoxWidth` to be describing the dimensions of a `TextBox`.

Comment: Up-voted as you are right.  I updated the code with new names... :)

Comment: As a noob to any type of programming, thank you. For some reason I thought the entity had to be named the same as the name of the textbox .

Answer (score 1):

In your situatuation it's better to rename ints, but you are ablealso to use this in simmilar situation

```
LengthtextBox = int.Parse(this.LengthtextBox.Text);
WidthtextBox = int.Parse(this.WidthtextBox.Text);
HeighttextBox = int.Parse(this.HeighttextBox.Text);
```

I think if you are new in programing it's good to know about this too, instead just renaming variables without understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove those definitions from `button1_Click()` method as you use the same names as the class variables inside this method:

```
int LengthtextBox;
int WidthtextBox;
int HeighttextBox;
```

And change the name of the variables:

```
int length;
int width;
int height;

length= int.Parse(LengthtextBox.Text);
width= int.Parse(WidthtextBox.Text);
height= int.Parse(HeighttextBox.Text);
paint = 350;

answer = (length* width* height) / paint;
```