# Exceptions attempting to parse a value from a text box

Tags: c#, parsing

I am writing a simple budgeting application for practice as I am learning C# and I am having difficulty getting an integer value from a text box on a form.

```
int newBudget;
newBudget = Int32.Parse(newCat.budgetBox.Text);
```

`newCat` is the name of the form I am using, and the box above it from which I retrieved a string value worked correctly. This code appears to be the same as that which was recommended in other threads. I am aware that I have not implemented proper error handling for inputs that are not integers, but testing it with only integers has caused these errors.

Comment: It's really hard to help you because you haven't told us what exception you are getting, which “string value worked correctly”, what “other threads” you are talking about, nor which “integers has caused these errors”. Remember, we can't see your screen, you have to put these things in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when trying to get an int from textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126116/error-when-trying-to-get-an-int-from-textbox)

Comment: The actual error message was: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @EthanRedrup this error message means that `newCat.budgetBox.Text` is not an integer. Put a breakpoint on this line in the debugger and examine the contents of `newCat.budgetBox.Text` when the breakpoint hits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
int newBudget;
if (Int32.TryParse(newCat.budgetBox.Text, out newBudget))
{
    //use the value
}
```

...to avoid getting an exception when using not valid int values.

More about [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the exception but I'm assuming it's a [FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which means the string is not in the correct format.

You'd be better off using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Int32.TryParse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) which does not throw an exception on invalid input:

```
int newBudget;
if (!int.TryParse(newCat.budgetBox.Text, out newBudget))
{
    // Handle error ...
}
else
{
    // Do something with newBudget ...
}
```